# JComboBox with JButton into TextField

Tags: java, jbutton, jcombobox

I want to detect what `JComboBox` item is selected when I click the `JButton`. The result will be placed in a `TextField` that I've stacked up in my action performed.

For example, when I select an appropriate number then it will classified into something using the JButton and the result will be on TextField.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class mFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
JLabel lblAge = new JLabel("Age");
JComboBox cboAge = new JComboBox();
JButton btnClass = new JButton("Classification");
JTextField txtField = new JTextField();
JButton btnClose = new JButton("Close");

public mFrame()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(400,200);

    add(lblAge);
    add(cboAge);
    add(btnClass);
    add(txtField);
    add(btnClose);

    lblAge.setBounds(10,10,100,20);
    cboAge.setBounds(140,10,120,20);
    btnClass.setBounds(10,30,120,20);
    txtField.setBounds(140,30,120,20);
    btnClose.setBounds(200,105,70,20);
    for (int j = 10; j < 101; j++) cboAge.addItem(new Integer(j));

    cboAge.addActionListener(this);
    btnClass.addActionListener(this);
    txtField.addActionListener(this);
    btnClose.addActionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent age)
{
    //if (age.getSource() == btnClass)
    {
        //
    if (age.getSource() == btnClose)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
}
  class StartHere
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new mFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: cant put it on edit i dont know why

Comment: done edit please check

Answer (score 0):

first you don't need `addActionListener()` for txtField and cboAge
because you are not doing anything when action is performed there.
just do it for buttons.

and this is how `actionPerformed()` can be (**note**: i changed `ActionEvent age` to `ActionEvent e`)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == btnClass){
        String selectedValue = cboAge.getSelectedItem().toString();

        // if you need it as integer...
        int age = Integer.parseInt(selectedValue);

        // do your classification processing... assuming output value is assigned in String result.

        //ex for classification processing:
        String result = "";
        if(age>=10 && age<=19){
              result = "Teenage";
        }else if(age>=20 && age<=28){
              result = "blah blah";
        }//... and so on...

        txtField.setText(result);
    }else if (e.getSource() == btnClose){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i tried this, but what if i got specific classifications each number i select in combo box?

for example

when i click 10 to 19 the classification result will be Teenager
when i click 20 to 30 etc. the classification result will be Adult and such that!! 
 
i can get the result of only 1 number!, sorry im still new to programming thing and need help to explore more

Comment: that;s what i mean by `do your classification processing...` you can compare `age` as integer for the categories you have, ex, `if(age>=10 && age<=19){result = "Teenage";}` ... and so on

Comment: bad operand types for binary operator '>=' T_T

Comment: maybe its in my JCreator, ill try this tomorrow at school